# How does he know that the following matrix is invertible, and how would you solve the following system if it wasn't?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

https://youtu.be/B2wqZKZv3O0?t=929

[image]

[image: the fo]

He likely just calculated the determinant, but I am wondering, is it because the system of equations he is solving isn't impossible? Would the matrix not be invertible if it was?

Also if the matrix wasn't invertible how could I solve this? I figure I could use the expanded matrix and put the results on the RHS and when I put it in the rref I just solve the simplified system. Is this correct?

Comment: If the matrix is not invertible then the system could either have no solutions or infinitely many. If it is invertible then there is exactly one solution

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Is there any way of knowing how many solutions it has before solving it?

Comment: Determine the number of linearly independent rows/columns (so in essence you do have to solve it). In this case it is easy because the determinant is not equal to $0$

Comment: You apply Gaussian elimiation and find out. Of course knowing it's a special matrix with always nonzero determinant helps...

Comment: Alternate way to solve it would be to apply Lagrange interpolation and get $a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 = 1 + \frac{1}{6} (x-2) (x-3) (x-4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that this matrix is of the form: \begin{equation} A =\begin{bmatrix}1&x&x^2&x^3
\\1&2x&(2x)^2&(2x)^3
\\1&3x&(3x)^2&(3x)^3
\\1&4x&(4x)^2&(4x)^3\\\end{bmatrix}\end{equation}

So, if the kernel of the matrix was non-empty, that is, \begin{equation}A\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\end{bmatrix} = 0\end{equation}
there would be 4 roots of the equation: \begin{equation} a_1 + a_2x+a_3x^2+a_4x^3 = 0\end{equation} Namely, *x, 2x, 3x, and 4x*, which contradicts the fundamental theorem of algebra as a polynomial of 3rd degree has at most 3 real roots.

As Henno Brandsma pointed out, this is the Vandermode matrix, and this invertibility holds generally. Further, it proves that any non-degenerate set of *n* distinct points in R^2 can be interpolated by an *(n - 1)* degree polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix *is* invertible because it has non-zero determinant, it's a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) of order $4$ with $\alpha_1=1 < \alpha_2= 2 < \alpha_3=3 < \alpha_4 = 4$, so the determinant is $(4-3)(4-2)(4-1)(3-1)(3-2)(2-1) = 12$. It will always be non-zero for distinct $\alpha_i$. So you know the linear system (whatever the right hand side is) will always have a unique solution.